# Power BI trigger for over a a certain value in 7 days

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I was wondering if it is possible to create a trigger (colour red/green) for if a value surpasses a certain number within a certain time frame.

My example would be if a value is greater than 20 in the past 7 days flag as red. the rest green.

Thanks in advance,
James.

Comment: Hi James, what have you tried so far? Any websearches? Any DAX formulas that failed? Also, if you could provide some testdata, that would help everyone help you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting). Now read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question, please!